# Match delimited values from two columns

Tags: sql, azure, split

```
col1    col2                   col3 
21      12;13;45;67;       65;43;66;34;33
23      45;67;23;13;       45;78;89;09;32
```

I have something like above which I got from so many joins. One of my where condition is to check col1 is in col2 which I did with:

```
... col1 IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(col2, ';')`.
```

I have or condition to check col2 is in col3. How can I do that in sql.

Goal is col2 should be either in col1 or col3.

Comment: my alignement is gone so col1:21 col2:12;13;45;67 col3:45;67;23;13

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: it just a straight forward sql query. azure sql server

Comment: So any of the values from col2 must also exist in col3?

Comment: @salman yes either in col1 or in col3

Answer (score 0):

A query like this works:

```
SELECT value  
FROM yourdata cross apply string_split(col2, ';')
where value in (col1)
and value in (SELECT value  
FROM yourdata cross apply string_split(col3, ';'))
```

Data:

```
Col1    Col2               Col3 
-----------------------------------------
21      12;13;45;67;       65;43;66;34;23  --  notice 23 in col3
23      45;67;23;13;       45;78;89;09;32
```

Comment: I want to find out col 2 :" 12;13;45;67; " at least one(12 or 13 or 45 or 67)  in col1 :21 or in col3:(65;43;66;34;23

Comment: yes, this query works for your data. As a demo, I have included 23 in col3. 23 is present across all three (col1, col2, col3). so the output is 23

Comment: if nothing is present across all three, query returns nothing.

Comment: this is not working in where condition . I will make my question more clear where (23;42;47;89) in (78;12;90;23). this is what im trying to do. Any one of the tuple is present in another tuple